# How to convert file .png to .CUBE using PHP

Tags: php, converters

I can't find the code for this problem, maybe somebody can help me, i want to make if file.png uploaded, and then I press generate button, it will be .CUBE and auto download it

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below, it worked for me!

```
$fileupload = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
$fileName = pathinfo($fileupload)['filename'];
$fileExtension=pathinfo($fileupload)['extension'];
if($fileExtension=="png")
{
    $fileupload =  $fileName.".CUBE";
}
$filePathURL=$fileupload;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'], "$filePathURL");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Type: application/stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileupload);
```